# it's possible to set timer on reducer state? React + Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

it's possible to set a timer to clear some reducer state? i have a state to show message of "success", "error", "warning"

Example:

Reducer:

```
const statusState = {
   status: {action: '', result: ''}
}

...

CASE fetchContent:
    return {
      ...state,
      contents: [...state.contents, action.data],
      status: {
        ...state.status,
        action: action.type,
        result: action.result
      }
    }
```

Component:

```
render(){
   cost { status } = this.props

   if(status.action == "something" && status.result == "success"){
      alert("success");
   }
}

const mapStateToProps = store => ({
       status: store.initialState.status
   });

   export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Component);
```

if i don't clear status.action and status.result the alert will show all the time, it's possible to set a timer to clear it?

Comment: Are you sure about the component syntax? Sounds strange that you have all in the render method...

Comment: @SilvioBiasiol fixed, didn't notice hahaha.

Comment: you could use mapDispatchToProps and clear the status value

Comment: Sure it's possible. The most appropriate place to do it is an action. It also assumes that you add the respective case in your reducer.

Comment: Side note: Using `alert` in `render()` looks inappropriate. From the React's POV `render()` should only have DOM output, and `alert` has no relation to DOM.

Comment: @hindmost thanks for the advice, in fact i'm not using alert on render() it was a example (my fault), i'm using a modal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a clear action which clears status.action and status.result. Create a javscript timeout function that calls clear action after timeout. Something like below:

```
 clearStatus = ()=>{
       setTimeout(
        function() {
            //create a action that clears status and result
        },3000
       );
    }   

     render(){
           cost { status } = this.props

           if(status.action == "something" && status.result == "success"){
             //showMessage 
             clearStatus();
           }
        }
```

Comment: Works perfectly, just need to use arrow function
setTimeout( () => { this.props.resetStatus() }, 3000)